# How can I automatically be warned if a specific file changes?

Tags: git, githooks

I have a php project, and when I pull from another repository and the composer.lock file gets changed, I'm supposed to run `composer.phar install --dev`. How can git automatically warn me / ask me if I want to run this command? I suppose some sort of hook would do the trick, but how can I get information regarding only what has changed before and after the pull in it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It depends on what option you use when pulling:

### No option : git fetch and git merge are run

You can write your own [post-merge git hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_post_merge):

> This hook is invoked by git merge, which happens when a git pull is done on a local repository. The hook takes a single parameter, a status flag specifying whether or not the merge being done was a squash merge. This hook
>          cannot affect the outcome of git merge and is not executed, if the merge failed due to conflicts.

This hook should work for you (save this as executable file `.git/hooks/post-merge`):

```
#!/bin/sh

CHANGED=`git diff HEAD@{1} --stat -- $GIT_DIR/../composer.lock | wc -l`
if [ $CHANGED -gt 0 ];
then
    echo "composer.lock has changed!"
    composer.phar install --dev
fi
```

### --rebase : git fetch and git rebase are run

You can write your own [post-checkout git hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_post_checkout):

> This hook is invoked when a git checkout is run after having updated the worktree. The hook is given three parameters: the ref of the previous HEAD, the ref of the new HEAD and a flag indicating whether the checkout was a branch checkout or a file checkout

This hook should work for you (save this as executable file `.git/hooks/post-checkout`):

```
#!/bin/sh

CHANGED=`git diff $1 $2 --stat -- $GIT_DIR/../composer.lock | wc -l`
if [ $CHANGED -gt 0 ];
then
    echo "composer.lock has changed!"
    composer.phar install --dev
fi
```

### UPDATE

Here is [my personal set of git hooks](https://github.com/greg0ire/git_template).

Comment: What do you mean by pull? Because simple fetch will not update local branch. pull will, but only if it was tracking branch. As long as your operation involves updating your control file, post-checkout hook should work. I would recommend testing it by doing something like `git reset --hard HEAD~20` (rewind head by many commits), and then `git pull --rebase` - hook will be called and fire if control file was changed (I tested it locally).

Comment: I mean: pull from a remote repository. I tested with a very simple script and it does not work. `git pull --rebase` does work.

Comment: There is a `post-merge hook`, but it does not have the same arguments as the `post-checkout`. Too bad...

Comment: In fact, it might be usable when the merge is a non fast-forward merge: 'HEAD^' is the commit before the pull so it should work in this case. Any idea for the fast-forward?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an interesting gist: https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/7996717 I've adapted it for your question.

post-merge git hook is executed when you merge branches or when you do `git pull`.

post-merge hook ([read docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge))

```bash
#/usr/bin/env bash
# MIT © Sindre Sorhus - sindresorhus.com
# forked by naXa! - naxa.by

# Git hook to run a command after `git merge` / `git pull` if a specified file was changed.
# Run `chmod +x post-merge` to make it executable then put it into `.git/hooks/`.

changed_files="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD)"

check_run() {
  echo "$changed_files" | egrep --quiet "$1" && echo "$2"
}

# In this example it's used to print a warning if composer.lock has been changed
check_run composer.lock "Run `composer.phar install --dev`"
```

post-checkout git hook is executed when you switch between branches or when you do `git rebase`.

post-checkout hook ([read docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout))

```bash
#/usr/bin/env bash
# MIT © Sindre Sorhus - sindresorhus.com
# forked by naXa! - naxa.by

# Git hook to run a command after `git checkout` if a specified file was changed.
# Run `chmod +x post-merge` to make it executable then put it into `.git/hooks/`.

# terminate gracefully on a file checkout (retrieving a file from the index)
# uncomment the below line if you don't want to run this hook on a file checkout (for example on git->revert in IntelliJ IDEA)
# [ $3 -eq 0 ] && { exit 0; }

changed_files="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id $1 $2)"

check_run() {
  echo "$changed_files" | egrep --quiet "$1" && echo "$2"
}

# In this example it's used to print a warning if composer.lock has been changed
check_run composer.lock "Run `composer.phar install --dev`"

exit 0;
```

You may notice that I've changed `grep` to `egrep` here. It is done in order to be able to search using a fancy expression. For example `"file1.txt|file2.txt"` where `|` is used as an OR operator.

Comment: Nice ! For the record, I ended up using `git diff-tree` too. Here is [what I built](https://github.com/greg0ire/git_template/blob/master/template/hooks/change_detector.sh)