# Update node modules when package-lock has changed

Tags: git, npm, githooks

We are using git and npm in our project.

We often pull the changes made by our colleagues. Most of the time, this is enough, but if our colleague did update a dependency, just pulling the new `package.json` and the new `package-lock.json` won't be enough. We alson need to run `npm install` to update our `node_modules`.

The issue is that if we forget about the `npm install`, we end up with errors that will take us time to identify and finally realize: "Oh! That dependency was updated!".

So, what I would really like, is a kind of hook that would, each time the file `package-lock.json` is changed, run `npm install`.

Being totally newbie with hooks, I have some problems though:

- What hook should I use? Is `post-update` what I'm looking for? Or should it be `post-receive`? Or `post-checkout` maybe?
- How can I get the information if `package-lock.json` was updated in the changes I pulled?
- Is this the correct way to achieve my goal or is there another way?

**Edit**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840184/how-can-i-automatically-be-warned-if-a-specific-file-changes) that seems to fix my issue perfectly. I will make it an answer once I checked that it's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge

So, how to use it? Well, you will need to write some lines of code to handle that. The problem is that this resides inside your .git folder. You can configure it as a global "thing", but yet need to control and distribute it to all your colleagues.

I wrote a tool https://pypi.org/project/hooks4git/ to be simple enough to be used, and yet flexible enough to be used in any programming language.

It is a tool written in Python, so yes, you need python on the OS.
But after that, you can create your custom "check-if-packagejson-was-changed-and-do-npm-install.js" and link it to a .hooks4git.ini file, and that's it.

This file goes within the repository.

I just noticed that I missed a few hooks, post-merge in particular, and added support for this... It is building on Travis right now! The main idea is that I collect all data I can, and call your custom script at the right event. You code the rest on your preferred language.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This definitely is cool. Though, I can't start to figure out how I can detect a change in the `package-lock` file. Moreover, I am using `git pull --rebase`, but there is no `post-rebase` hook...

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148206/executing-a-git-hook-after-pull-rebase it says that a post-checkout is called. Needs testing. If it works, documentation is here https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout You can easily try with hooks4git doing echos on every hook to find it out. Then, you need, with provided parameters, your piece of code to actually check if the file changed or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I linked in my edit a solution from StackOverflow that should fulfill my needs. I didn't have time to test it yet.

Comment: Interesting. I am adding extra -useful- stuff to hooks4git. Will check to see if this can be leveraged or not. Tks.